# Remove list of phrases if they are present in a text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a list of phrases *(over 100)* which I want to be removed from a text file *(products.txt)* which has lines of text inside it *(they are tab separated / new line each)*. So that the results which do not match the list of phrases will be re-written in the current file.

```
#cd .\Desktop\
$productlist = @(
        'example',
        'juicebox',
        'telephone',
        'keyboard',
        'manymore')
    
foreach ($product in $productlist) {
    
get-childitem products.txt | Select-String -Pattern $product -NotMatch | foreach {$_.line} | Out-File -FilePath .\products.txt
    
}
```

The above code does not remove the words listed in the $productlist, it simply outputs all links in products.txt again.

The lines inside of products.txt file are these:

```
productcatalog
product1example
juicebox038
telephoneiphone
telephoneandroid
randomitem
logitech
coffeetable
razer
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried doing a text replace on one line? none of your code seems to do any replacement of any sort. ///// PLEASE, add a sample of your `Products.txt` file so that folks will have an idea of how to structure both the "find" and the "replace".

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I updated the question so that it includes the contents of the file products.txt .
This part `Select-String Select-String -Pattern $product -NotMatch` gets the lines which are not in the lists and adds then following adds them to products.txt file. _(I am new in Powershell, I followed the MS documentation)_

Comment: thank you for the added info! [*grin*] ///// i managed to misunderstand your intent ... you want to REMOVE the entire line if the line matches any of the product list items. your problem seems to be the way that you are READING from and then WRITING to the same file. have you tried writing to a different file?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey No problem! :) Yes, even changing and adding a new file like like `Out-File -FilePath .\formatedproducts.txt` still nothing changes the same result _(all list is shown like the inputed one)_

Comment: please take a look at the Answer i posted. it seems to work as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution.  You need the parentheses otherwise the input file will be in use when trying to write to the file.  Select-string accepts an array of patterns.  I wish I could pipe 'path' to set-content but it doesn't work.

```
$productlist = 'example', 'juicebox', 'telephone', 'keyboard', 'manymore'

(Select-String $productlist products.txt -NotMatch) | % line |
  set-content products.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do what you want. it's somewhat more direct than what yo used. [*grin*] it uses the way that PoSh can act on an entire collection when it is on the LEFT side of an operator.

what it does ...

- fakes reading in a text file
  when ready to do this in real life, replace the whole `#region/#endregion` block with a call to `Get-Content`.
- builds the exclude list
- converts that into a regex OR pattern
- filters out the items that match the unwanted list
- shows that resulting list

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    when ready to do this for real, replace the whole "#region/#endregion" block with a call to Get-Content
$ProductList = @'
productcatalog
product1example
juicebox038
telephoneiphone
telephoneandroid
randomitem
logitech
coffeetable
razer
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

$ExcludedProductList = @(
        'example'
        'juicebox'
        'telephone'
        'keyboard'
        'manymore'
        )
$EPL_Regex = $ExcludedProductList -join '|'

$RemainingProductList = $ProductList -notmatch $EPL_Regex

$RemainingProductList
```

output ...

```
productcatalog
randomitem
logitech
coffeetable
razer
```

Comment: Thank you Lee, code makes total sense but for some reason it shows all the list from _products.txt_ and at the end a `True` line.
Will the regex work if there are characters or other words before each phrase like `www.logitech.com` since there is the phrase `logitech`? Could that be it?

Comment: @RonaldLexburg - if you run the code i posted _exactly as shown_, does it give you the same result as i show?